# Using dd to clone a server with multiple partitions

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, dd, clone

Is it possible to use dd to clone multiple partitions to one .iso file?

I have a system I want to clone to another box, with multiple partitions. Can dd be used to perform this task? From what I can tell (never used dd and new to linux) dd can targer only one at a time. Is there a way to do this and image the whole thing in one go?

```
    Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             7.8G  470M  6.9G   7% /
/dev/sda7              18G  530M   16G   4% /scratch
/dev/sda6             3.9G  185M  3.5G   5% /var
/dev/sda2              12G  2.7G  8.4G  25% /usr
/dev/sda5              20G  1.1G   18G   6% /opt
tmpfs                 2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The digit at the ends  is about the partition.
- Without the digit you are talking about a disk so with the partition layout.

So drop the digits ...

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

will clone your 1st disk to your 2nd disk. If you want to see progress:

```
sudo apt install pv
dd if=/dev/sda | pv | dd of=/dev/sdb
```

Be very very careful about what you put at the "of"/output file: it WILL destroy the destination. Contents of sdb are gone. Unless you have a backup.

Comment: Ah, so since all the partitions are on one disk (sda) just dd sda. NICE! Thank you

Comment: After that .iso is created it should be bootable, and I can install it on another system correct? just want to make sure I am understanding this utility correctly. Thanks for the help

Comment: You do not "install" a diskdump. You do another diskdump to write it onto the disk. And it might not be bootable since it depends on where and what the bootloader is. I generally fix that on the machine itself.